# How to always revert to a max 24hr period when adding time values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web page which calculates various figures to arrive at a specific operating time in a table, each timestamp is summed up with a pre-calculated amount based on couple pf variables, but there are large blocks of hours involved which will give me a total output that exceeds 24 hours. I found a script here on SO that reverts from military time to AM/PM format, but because the sum can exceed the 24 figure, the script only revises the time if it is under 25 hours. If I get 39 hours as a total, I end up with 27:00 PM, whereas it should read 3 AM. How to revise the script so that it cycles through 24 hours and gives me an accurate AM or PM as a result? Here is the JSFiddle link for the script which revises the sum hour total: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xEuUR/4/ --->punch in a figure greater than 24:59 and you'll see what I mean. I have a link to the page I'm working on, and the script is pretty complicated, so I'll post the link to the live page and will try to post samples of the JS that are relevant if I get requests to do so(or maybe if anyone even notices this post): 
http://dcalvitti.altervista.org/push.html

Code for the hour revision script:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox1"/>
<input type="button" id="b1" value="convert 12 hr"/>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 function am_pm_to_hours(time) {
    var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
    var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
    if (AMPM == "pm" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
    if (AMPM == "am" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
    var sHours = hours.toString();
    var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
    if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
    if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
    return (sHours +':'+sMinutes);
}

function hours_am_pm(time) {
    var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var min =  Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
    if (min < 10) min = "0" + min;
    if (hours < 12) {
        return hours + ':' + min + ' AM';
    } else {
        hours=hours - 12;
        hours=(hours < 10) ? '0'+hours:hours;
        return hours+ ':' + min + ' PM';
    }
}
$('#b1').click(function(){
     var n = $('.textbox1').val();
     var n1 =n.split('_');
    var time = hours_am_pm(n1[0]+n1[1]).replace('::',':');;
    $('.result').text(time);
}); 
$('#b2').click(function(){
    var n = $('.textbox1').val();
     var n1 =n.split('_');
    var time = am_pm_to_hours(n1[0]+':'+n1[1]+' '+n1[2]).replace('::',':');
    $('.result').text(time);
});

});
```

The relevant bit is ID="b1" which converts a 24:00 format into 12AM or 12PM-format. I removed the "B2" portion as I don't need it.
Any tip is helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a small change is needed.  Simply use "%24" on these lines:

```
function am_pm_to_hours(time) {
var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1])%24;

function hours_am_pm(time) {
var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1])%24;
```

That's it!  :)